# How to install freeBSD on a separate partition?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, installation, freebsd

I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 installed and have a free 63GB partition.

I'm trying to install freeBSD on it. I get a "Add partition" prompt when installing
which requests

- Type
- Size
- Mountpoint

I found out that freeBSD uses a UFS file system type. I then entered the following info

- Type: freebsd-ufs
- Size: 63GB
- MountPoint: /

But I keep getting the following error:

- Invalid argument

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had written an answer explaining `fdisk` partition codes. After a bit of research I decided it was completely wrong and deleted it. According to [this page](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/bsdinstall-partitioning.html) (which I imagine you have seen) `freebsd-ufs` is indeed the correct file system type.

I *guess* you are running into problems because you have too many primary partitions. Only four primary partitions are allowed. Since you already have 2 other OSs  installed, you probably already have the maximum four allowed. So, what you need to do is delete the empty 64GB partition and recreate it as a [extended](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/file/structPartitions-c.html) instead of [primary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_partition#Primary_partition) partition. I would recommend you do this through `gparted` on Linux but you can probably do it through the freeBSD installer as well.

Once you have converted the primary 63GB partition into a extended one, you can go ahead and create other [logical](http://www.applexsoft.com/glossary/partition-types.html) partitions within it and install freeBSD on one of them.

Comment: The 4 partition limit only applies to MBR partition tables. Modern computers can use [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) which can contain at least 128 partitions. I don't know what the default for a Windows 7 machine is, though.

Comment: @RolandSmith yes, but there is nothing in the question suggesting the OP is using GPT. GPT is still relatively new (I have yet to use it for example) and the symptoms described do sound like it could be an MBR max partition issue.